# Finding a function $f$ such that $0 < f(s_{k+1}) - f(s_{k}) \leq \frac{1}{p(k)}, s_k=\frac{k}{k+1}$ for a polynomial $p$ of degree at least three.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence of rationals $\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)_{k=1}^\infty$, and denote the $k$th element of the sequence as $s_k$. I was wondering what would be such a function $f$ that $$0 < f(s_{k+1}) - f(s_{k}) \leq \frac{1}{p(k)}$$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree at least three. Furthermore, could such an $f$ be the anti-derivative of some Lebesgue integrable function $g$ such that e.g.

$$\int_{s_k}^{s_{k+1}}g(t)dt \leq k^{-3}$$

It might be easiest to start with first understanding what such an $f$ has to be. To this end, I have not yet managed to understand properly how the behavior of the $s_k$s should be reflected on the function $f$ in the sense that it seems that even a shifted gamma function (shifted by a constant such that the difference is always positive) does not seem to work. As of writing I don't how to construct such an $f$, or to argue why it cannot exist.

Comment: Try $f(x) = (1 - 1/x)^3$.

Comment: @DS Thanks! Don't know why that function didn't come to my mind at first.

Comment: The function $f(x)={1\over 3}(x-1)^3$ looks simpler. You may consider $u(x)=f(x+1).$ Then your requirements are more transparent (around $0$) and $u(x)={1\over 3}x^3.$